# Avoiding try-catch blocks with async/await error handling

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, async-await

I'm using async/await syntax in my new express project and I'm looking for a good error handling approach.

With async/await handling errors usually looks like this:

```
app.use('/', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const result = await asyncWork();
    res.send(result);
  }
  catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});
```

But writing try-catch blocks in all the middlewares makes code hard to read.

One approach would be to use a wrapper function like this:

```
const wrap = fn => (...args) => {
  const fnReturn = fn(...args);
  const next = args[args.length - 1];

  return Promise.resolve(fnReturn).catch(next);
};

app.use('/', wrap(async doWork));
```

It's ok but we have to wrap every middleware to make this works:

```
app.use('/', wrap(async doWork));
app.use('/auth', wrap(async doAuth));
app.use('/users', wrap(async doUsers));
```

And it looks redundant to me.

Do you recommend using [express-promise-router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-promise-router) package?

Is there a better way for handling this without extra package?

Comment: You might benefit too from a more modern framework. Express comes from a time without promises and async/await, so it's all callback-based.

Comment: Here you can do this without any lib https://stackoverflow.com/a/61833084/6482248 It looks cleaner